# Custom extended Android DatePickerDialog without title

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I've an extended DatePickerDialog, but I'm not able to hide the title (on 5.+).

I tried the `requestWindowFeature` function on some places, but I don't know where the right is.

```
public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener listener, Reklamation reklamation, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    super(context, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "noTitle:" + requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try by:-  DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
                  dialog.setTitle("");

Comment: but then I have an empty title (until I change the date) ||
I don't want this title with the selected date in Material design

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom Layout with a date picker inside of it :)

this will give you more flexibility than the custom view you working with then

inflate the layout and store it into a view as follow :

```
LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
View Customview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutname,null);
//assign it to the dialog
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(customview);
// add the listeners  .. etc
// create and show the dialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

## or

```
setTitle("");
```

then inside the datepicker extend the listener on dateChange as follow :

```
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
    setTitle("");
}
```

### i hope this will help you

Comment: do I really need a custom layout to just hide the title of the dialog?

Comment: im saying that it will give more flexibility and it will make the rendering process faster :)
at the the end there is more than a way to solve it but i recommend this method its easier , faster and flexible :)

Comment: my problem is, that I need the `extend` version, because I need to manipulate the dialog

Comment: you can try the second solution :)

Comment: thx, that is also in the comments of my question... || I don't need an empty title

Comment: then there is a solution to create a custom date picker then create a custom layout then add the custom date picker inside the custom layout and inflate it into a dialog but you have to set the width and hieght for both the custom datepicker and its parent to wrap_content :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, should work buddy:

`AlertDialog` have `setCustomHeader` method, using it and set a custom view with `zero` width, `zero` height. It will work

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
timePickerDialog.setCustomTitle(linearLayout);
```